# How do I know if I have rejected a gdpr message in android?

Tags: android

I opened the gdpr window on Android and selected Do not consent.
However, as a result of the consentInformation.canRequestAds() code, it says that ads can be displayed.
Even if I read the status with consentInformation.getConsentStatus(), it continues to show OBTAINED.
If I have been rejected for gdpr how do I find out if I was rejected?